# Java - synchronizing getSize() on List

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
List<Ball> myObjs = myThreads[threadIndex].getMyObjList();
int initialSize = Collections.synchronizedList(myObjs).size();
```

Throws ConcurrentModificationException. I have also tried putting this in a
synchronized(myObjs) block, but it also didn't work. What is the solution? Everywhere else where I use this list, it is in an synchronized(block).

P.S. This error also ends up producing BrokenBarrierException. (yes, I am using cyclic barrier for synchronization)

EDIT: Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1091)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:921)
at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.size(Collections.java:1573)
at Part2.Animation.processCollisions(MyClass.java:133) // This is the call to size()
```

EDIT: The loop looks like

```
for (int threadIndex=0; threadIndex < numThreads; threadIndex++) {
  List<Ball> myObjs = myThreads[threadIndex].getMyObjList();
  int initialSize = Collections.synchronizedList(myObjs).size();
}
```

And regardless of numThreads, the exception happens when threadIndex=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code for some of the `List` classes, I can't see how it is possible that calling `size()` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  It would help if you showed us a stack trace.

---

But in the meantime, you appear to have a fundamental misconception about what `Collections.synchronizedList` does.  What it does is create and return a list wrapper that will ensure that operations *on the same wrapper instance* are synchronized.

It does not in anyway prevent threads from performing unsynchronized operations *on underlying list*; i.e. the list object that you just wrapped.   If a thread has the reference for the underlying list, it can access it directly without going thrpough the wrapper.  And neither does it do anything to synchronize operations using *different* wrappers for the same underlying list.  So if you call `Collections.synchronizedList` twice on the same list, you will create two distinct wrappers that do not synchronize with each other.

So, in fact your `Collections.synchronizedList(myObjs).size()` does not perform any meaningful synchronization at all.  No other thread can get hold of the synchronized list wrapper that is created, so no other thread can synchronize with this one via the wrapper.

Comment: +1, but surely LinkedList.size() has to iterate the list, which is vulnerable to concurrent modifications?

Comment: @EJP - Nope.  Here's the implementation from the `java.util.LinkedList` class - `public int size() {return size;}`.  I'm not saying it is impossible for `size()` to throw a CME ... but I can't find any examples.

Comment: Ah ... I see.  It is on a sublist!  Anyway, my point about the way you are doing the synchronization still stands.  And furthermore, if you are using a sublists, you need to make sure that nothing modifies the parent list either.

Comment: I am not using sublists, the exception comes from this line int initialSize = Collections.synchronizedList(myObjs).size();
and I get your point that this doesn't solve anything. But how do I solve it then???

Comment: Actually, you ARE using a sublist, because the stacktrace clearly shows that the exception is being thrown in a call to `java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size()`.  Maybe that is part of your problem.  I can't advise on how you should solve this without seeing / understanding more of your code.

Comment: Maybe size somehow uses sublist? The code is above, and I point exactly what line throws the exception, it is the one with the size() call.

Comment: I think you will find that `myObjs` is an instance of `java.util.ArrayList.SubList`

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by `subList()`, has nothing to do with synchronize.

`myObjs` is a result of subList(), actually myObjs is **view of original List**. If the original List is modified, `ConcurrentModificationException` will happen when `subList.size()` is called. It makes sense, view should be consistent to its original List.

Instead, you could get sub list like:

```
List mySubList = new ArrayList(originalList.subList(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` if you want to modify a list with 2 or above threads.

"This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException."

Comment: But they are not modifying it at the same time, that's why I don't see why this is necessary.Moreover, only one thread is adding objects to the list, the other is just modifying existing objects on it.

Comment: Also, this seems very slow. How can I explicitly lock and thus sync an array list?